# Publicist badge query

Tags: feature-request, publicity-badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [View progress towards Announcer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge)

Is there a way to find out how many unique IP queries have been made from the "link" provided under the question?

I was just wondering since I read that there is possibility of custom querying the stackoverflow database.

Answer (score 0):

There is not, unfortunately. I'd like this as well.

The database that is available to the public public is anonymized, and can't be used for this purpose.

Some people use a URL shortening service that will track clicks for them, but this is a bit sub-optimal.

[Here is a previous post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge) requesting the same thing.

Comment: This should be amended. It would mean great source of traffic if better link sharing tracking and instruction would be available. I just experimented with reddit and got announcer and booster in the same day. Now on one question I have over 2500 views already in couple of days and I still didn't get the publicist. Well go figure.