# Announcer Badge

Tags: discussion, support, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I “share” a link for the new badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/63684/how-do-i-share-a-link-for-the-new-badges)
>   [View progress towards Announcer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge)

How do you know how many unique IP Addresses have visited your post? and how many are still left to get you the Announcer Badge? I shared one Link and the question views were around 45 at that time. Now the total views are more than 80. So surely, more than 25 unique IP Addresses have visit my post. Why havn't I got the Announcer Badge Yet?

Comment: Note sure if this is a dupe or not: [View progress towards Announcer badge](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240) - it's a  feature request for "view my referrals"

Comment: Rather than re-asking a similar question, try improving the [old one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139006/176533).

Comment: Only people who visit the post **through your link** count towards the badge. You also have to be using the link generated specifically for you, it will look something like this with **your unique user id** appended to the end: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139109/142838

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The badge requires that 25 unique IP addresses have visited the **link you shared**, which contains your user id.

The view count displayed on a post is the total number of views, including visits that did not use your personalized link. There currently is nowhere to find out how many people used your link to visit a question, the Announcer badge is always a (nice) surprise.