# Searching for user:something returns every question and answer (13.3m results)

Tags: bug, search

### Problem

**Searching for** `user:something` (either a valid, or a non-existent user) **returns all posts on SO.**

### The story

I stumbled across [a question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge) where the OP's username was greyed out:

[image: a]

Curious as to if this was a bot or a banned user, or something else, I searched Meta for "Gnome"... but I didn't find anything relevant.

<sub>*My side-question is: who's Gnome?*</sub>

After that though, I searched Main for `user:gnome`

Yes, yes, I know, bad search syntax... Still, it matches **ALL** posts on the site:

From [Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com):

[image: b]

From [the search query](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3agnome):

[image: c]

[image: d]

Comment: I think he has deleted his profile. That's why it showing grayed username with no profile link.

Comment: Nothing to do with `user:gnome` in search. You may be interested in [user:skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Askeet)?

Comment: @hims056 That's my point. I was just explaining how I'd got there.

Comment: I suggest that you change your title, and/or the way your post is presented. It is quite confusing on first read (since people would just skim through your post).

Comment: The same thing is true for `is:bacon`, `isaccepted:possibly`, and `closed:unjustly`, i.e. any invalid search operator.

Comment: Well I also think this is a bug, the engine should return 0 results for invalid search terms. I wasted some time looking for what I searched in totally irrelevant results before I figured out what was going on...

Answer (score 2):

As for "Gnome" it was a long time member who asked (for his own private reasons) to delete his account.

Using the magic of Wayback Machine Internet Archive, we can still see his actual display name before he changed it at some later point. See [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20101031043830/https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/67240/view-progress-towards-announcer-badge):

> [image]

Comment: And you can see their old user id. Searching for `user:54262` correctly returns zero results.

Comment: @Martin true, the user account has been deleted. However the wayback machine archived the old profile page as well.

Answer (score 1):

When the username is greyed out, it means one of the following:

- The user has an account on another SE site and the post was migrated to a site where they don't have an account
- The user requested deletion of their account (generally this shows a greyed out `userXYZ`, but this seems to be a special case)

---

Also, User seaching the Data Explorer will give you a list of users who have an account on data.SE. You have to write a SQL query (Select * from users where DisplayName='Gnome') and run it (though in this case the account probably was deleted a long time ago and won't be on data.SE).

Comment: I think you've missed the thrust of the question: Danny is asking why **this query** causes the search engine to return **every single question and every single answer** from the database. "Who's Gnome?" is just a side question.

Comment: The post is not migrated, so the user is probably deleted.

Comment: @ToonKrijthe: Yep, though generally deleted users are have their usernames replaced with `userXYZ`

Answer (score 0):

> who's Gnome?

As his username displayed as grayed style and there is no link of his profile, I suspect that particular user has deleted his/her profile.