# Difference in score between Linked and Related questions - is it caching, or a bug?

Tags: feature-request, bug, related-questions, linked-questions, caching

I was browsing [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/205806/212576) discussion ([URL Shorteners cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/205806/212576)) and noticed in the related posts lists the following **difference in the score** on a [linked](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99136/212576) question ([Let Me Flag That For You - URL Shortener Cleanup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/99136/212576)).

> [image: caches]

I first noticed the related question be shown in linked nearly 3 minutes after [this comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/205806/url-shortners-cleanup#comment657277_205806) was left.

---

#### Hidden feature-request

Can we please stop displaying the same question from appearing in both lists? If a question is appearing under the linked posts list, it should not appear with the related questions too. Also, the difference in votes makes my eyes sore. It has been there for more than an hour now.

Comment: +1 for the feature request.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes they're cached separately since they have different rebuild triggers.  There's no need to regenerate the same HTML over and over again - so we cache the actual HTML output...this makes eliminating the same from both lists or syncing counts extremely non-trivial.  I wouldn't expect this to get a fix in the near future, just not a high priority.

Answer (score 4):

As [Nick says](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/206816/152859), this is indeed caching.

However, if you want to force a rebuild of the Linked Questions list, here are the steps to trigger it:

1. Copy the URL of the question having an out-of-synch linked question.
2. Go to that linked question.
3. On the linked question, post a new comment with the URL you copied in step 1.
4. Delete the comment.
5. Profit.

Based on [this other answer by Nick](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75046/questions-not-removed-from-linked-when-comments-are-deleted/187734#187734), this trigger a recalculation.

Comment: Now that's just dirty.

Comment: @JasonC so? It works. :)