# How can I get the shared link statistics?

Tags: support, share-this

There's a **share** permalink for each answer to a question (and for each question as well).
It's right next to the `flag` and `edit` links at the bottom of the answer.

How can I get the shared link statistics?

Comment: You can't. At best you can query for which users got the [announcer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/74/announcer), [booster](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/75/booster) and [publicist](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/76/publicist) badge for a specifc post

Comment: Related: [View progress towards Announcer, Booster, and Publicist badges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/67240/295232)